# What types/sizes of images do you need when using UIImage full screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm targeting iOS8 to release an application. So it'll be available on 4S, 5's, 6, 6+, and iPad 2+.

I have a `ViewController` where, I present a `UIImageView` that is the entire size of my `UIViewController`'s View.

My question is... what sizes do I need the image in. Am I going to need it in a special size for each device? Or does the 4s/5/6 all use the same ratios for example, while the 6+ has its own unique ratio? Or do I just use 1 image size and let it auto scale it (or will that stretch/skew the image)?

Also, what's the minimal size the image should be? If it's smaller than the native size of the iPhone 6+ for example, won't the quality of the image deteriorate?

Comment: u can used as large image as u want and make UiimageView mode =  aspectFit .But make sure your image is not small.it better to have minimum of size 1024×768 which is the size of ipad2

Comment: If you have to support iPhone (All Sizes). Then provide @1x,@2x,@3x images.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS8, you can use different size classes for different screens

use this [post](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-8-development-tips-for-iphone-6-and-iwatch-1c772554ffe0) to begin.

Also refer [this](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html) for more info about using different graphics for varying resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you need special size for each device by using image.xcassets.And this will help you alot - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: I'm doing this for icons etc. such as 1x/2x/3x at 22/44/66px for example. How does it work for full screen images though? Any links or specific sizes?

Answer (score 0):

The image in Imageview in 4s/5/6 devices render at @2x while that in 6+ it renders at @3x.So take an image and name it as Demo@2x.png and other image for 6+ having higher resolution , name it as Demo@3x.png.So When the image is placed in imageview , It will automatically takes Demo@2x.png for 4s/5/6 and Demo@3x.png for 6+.